# What kind of program can I use to make the following image?

Tags: 3d, abstract

Wondering how I can produce the same effect as the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This type of abstraction shapes typically called the "plexus style" model.

Not sure I got what effect exactly you mean... But to deliver a similar image for a one-time project I would use:

- Blender (to model the shapes)
- Photoshop (to blur, combine the shapes and background together, get in shine and fancy colored)

Alternatively, similar results can be produced well: in 3d-max, Maya, After Effects for sure.
Depends on how the resulted graphic to be used and the project details.

Search for "plexus", "plexus style" tutorials, and pick the software you know better to produce the result.

Hope it helps.

Comment: hey, thanks for the response. exactly what i was looking for. thank you so much!